# Object of class could not be converted while assigning to variable

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code:

```
private $settings;

private function __construct($settings) {
    $this->$settings = $settings;

    print "Created compiler";
}
```

Where the received $settings is an associative array loaded from a JSON file, the thing is a keep getting this error (Note is implementing a singleton pattern):

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

I'm sure this is a silly question, but I'm completely stuck at this moment...

Comment: `$this->settings`, no $

Comment: Do'h, Thanks Abhik I knew it was something stupid... Better to read carefully next time.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Probably great to post that as an answer so that KBorja can accept and this will stop folks coming to post an answer - or the OP deleting the question.

Comment: @Fluffeh ok posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is defined as

```
private $settings;
```

Now inside the constructor or within the same class you can access the member variable as

```
$this->variable_name ;
```

Note that you do not need to have a `$` before the variable name.

So in your case you should do as

```
$this->settings ;
```